# Lmer() R function does not return random but fixed intercepts

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, intercept

I'm using the lmer() function to run a random (intercept) mixed effect model as follow:

```
memC1 <- lmer(dev ~ tempW + tempB + sex + ls + (1|id), data = finalInfo)
```

With `finalInfo` dataframe as follow:

```
     id ls        dev  sex weight     temp       tempW    tempB
1     1 L1 0.08025824    M   0.57 13.39693 -0.01433593 13.41127
121   1 L2 0.14333160    M   0.57 14.45570  1.04442693 13.41127
241   1 L3 0.12072165    M   0.57 13.12785 -0.28342186 13.41127
361   1 L4 0.11681090    M   0.57 13.07488 -0.33638567 13.41127
481   1 L5 0.09477737    M   0.57 12.84387 -0.56739680 13.41127
601   1 L6 0.05421966    M   0.57 13.56838  0.15711333 13.41127
10   10 L1 0.07448295 <NA>     NA 13.45542          NA       NA
130  10 L2 0.13223586 <NA>     NA 14.18189          NA       NA
250  10 L3         NA <NA>     NA       NA          NA       NA
370  10 L4         NA <NA>     NA       NA          NA       NA
490  10 L5         NA <NA>     NA       NA          NA       NA
610  10 L6         NA <NA>     NA       NA          NA       NA
100 100 L1 0.08041054    F   0.58 13.47475  0.07786000 13.39689
220 100 L2 0.13058323    F   0.58 14.15907  0.76218210 13.39689
340 100 L3 0.15076350    F   0.58 13.19301 -0.20388247 13.39689
```

With `id` being a factor for each individual.

I got no error messages during the run, neither when I'm looking at the summary, but when I want to display the random intercepts (`coef(memC1)$id`) I got this:

```
      (Intercept)       temp        tempB         sexM      lsL2      lsL3       lsL4        lsL5       lsL6
1      -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
100    -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
105    -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
11     -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
13     -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
14     -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
16     -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18     -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
1810   -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18100  -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18101  -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18102  -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18103  -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18105  -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18107  -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
18108  -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
1811   -0.2288012 0.02297412 -0.000706292 -0.003196156 0.1035869 0.1159509 0.07302164 0.007018875 -0.1128562
```

All the intercepts are the same for every individual... How is this possible and what should I do to run a real random intercept mixed model ?... I suppose I'm missing something but I dont get what... Thanks for your help !

Comment: Just a side note: you have many NA and after dropping them (I suppose this is what lmer is doing by default) you are left with only two id's, 1 and 100.

Comment: You are right about that but even thought I have a considerable number of NA, I have 600 individuals so I still have a number of individuals with all information. The weird part is that when I add a random slope (1+tempW|id) then both intercepts and slopes are varying between individuals...

Comment: Try using the function *ranef()* on your model.

Answer (score 3):

This indicates that the estimated variance of the random intercepts was 0. You can confirm that this is true by looking at the top part of `summary(memC1)`.